# Laravel Ajax show message

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I want to show a message if the ajax was successful or not.
The code works so far, but I would like to add some messages.

My Controller delete function:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $streamID = 0)
{
    $stream = Stream::find($streamID);

    if($stream)
    {
        $stream->delete();
        File::delete($stream->image);
        return redirect()->route('stream.index')->with('success', 'Hooray');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('stream.index')->with('success', 'Not Hooray');
    }
}
```

And the ajax success and error part:

```
        success: function(data) {
            // show message?
        },
        error: function(data) {
            // show message?
        }
```

Comment: And how can help you? Tell you about `alert` function?

Comment: You can use Flash data https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

Comment: instead of return redirect()->route('stream.index')->with('success', 'Hooray');, return response()  ->json(['success' => 'Hooray']);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting from your php code, redirect from your ajax function and send json response to your ajax function as

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $streamID = 0)
{
    $stream = Stream::find($streamID);

    if($stream)
    {
        $stream->delete();
        File::delete($stream->image);
        return response() ->json(['code'=>200,'success' => 'Hooray']);
    }
    else
    {
        return response() ->json(['code'=>400,'success' => 'Not Hooray'])
    }
}
```

and in your ajax success function

```
 success: function(response) {
      alert(response.success);
      window.location.href = 'stream.index';
 },
 error: function(data) {
        // show message?
 }
```

Comment: How would you show it in laravels flash message style (box with green / red background)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the previous answer to this:

```
    ....
    if($stream) { 
       $stream->delete(); 
       File::delete($stream->image);
       return response()->json(['code'=>200,'success' => 'Hooray'],200); 
} 
     else { 
          return response()->json(['code'=>400,'success' => 'Not Hooray'],200);
    }
```

Comment: Hi but where / how do I  add the success message in the ajax?

Comment: @utdev I posted an answer to your comment hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap, add this anywhere you want your alert to display

```
<div id="ajax-alert" class="alert" style="display:none"></div>
```

Modify your script to this:

```
success: function(response){
    If(response.code === 200) {
        $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-sucess').show(function(){
            $(this).html(response.success);
        });
    }
    If(response.code === 400){
        $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-danger').show(function(){
            $(this).html(response.success);
        });
    }
}, 
error: function(data) { 
    alert ('Ajax run unsuccessful');
 }
```